# Caption left align with first word

Tags: tables, floats, captions, align

For a scientific article I am required to format captions of figures and tables in such a way that whenever it is longer than one line, the second (and third, etc.) line aligns with the first word of the caption (not the Figure 1:, but the actual first word).

How do I make this work?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! A minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that))  is greatly appreciated. Nevertheless maybe your questions is already answered.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use the `caption` package with the `format=hang` option.

[image: figure caption]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[format=hang]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}

    \caption{This tends to be a very long figure caption which is really superfluous, but of course breaks the line.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look to the [starter tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour). Instead of "Thank you", you can mark the answer as "accepted" and vote for it. Accepting means that it worked for you.